# parsing a relative clause "the gravitas she felt was appropriate to her office"

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses

I came across the following sentence:

> The head of the committee never failed to carry herself with the
>   gravitas she felt was appropriate to her office.

I feel that this construction came from "she felt the gravitas was appropriate to her office", but here "the gravitas" seems to be the subject of a noun clause, rather than the object of verb “felt". So how could it be translated into an attributive clause like "the gravitas she felt was appropriate to her office"?

Comment: You're assuming that it came from a different form without there being any reason to make that assumption. Your question is making an unsubstantiated claim—and then asking how it got from that other place to where it is now. But without any more context, the sentence is exactly what it is—and there *was* no translation that took place.

Comment: @JasonBassford Sorry for my misunderstanding. Could you help me to parse the original sentence? Was "the gravitas" the object of "felt"? I think it is the case but I couldn't explain the existence of "was"...

Comment: *[It] **was** appropriate to her office.* What *was*? *[The gravitas she felt*].

Comment: @JasonBassford  But in this case didn't we need a "which" before "was"?

Comment: @JasonBassford _It was the gravitas she felt that was appropriate to her office_ doesn't make sense to me. The more salient reading should be _It was the gravitas that she felt was appropriate to her office_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sentence contains a relative clause *she felt was appropriate to her office* that is integrated into the noun phrase *the gravitas she felt was appropriate to her office*. Putting *that* or *which* before the relative clause would make it obvious:

> *The head of the committee never failed to carry herself with the gravitas* (*that|which*) *she felt was appropriate to her office.*

Note that either *that* or *which* is necessary if you leave out *she felt*:

> *The head of the committee never failed to carry herself with the gravitas that|which was appropriate to her office.*

Comment: Thanks. Actually what get me stuck is the role "the gravitas" plays in this sentence. If it is considered to be object of "felt", I think the "was" shouldn't appear, that is, "appropriate" is enough as a object complement...

Comment: Just think of 'felt' here as 'thought'. _The head of the committee never failed to carry herself with the gravitas she **thought** was appropriate to her office._

Comment: @likemath - or *considered*.